# Eslint accusing unused property error with useCallback

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, eslint

I'm destructuring a larger object received by parameter in a Hook called useCallback from Reactjs, however, ESLINT gives me the following message:

```
'to' PropType is defined but prop is never usedeslintreact/no-unused-prop-types
'icon' PropType is defined but prop is never usedeslintreact/no-unused-prop-types
'title' PropType is defined but prop is never usedeslintreact/no-unused-prop-types
```

Why exactly am I getting this message when they are being used? Should I fix some rule in eslint? Is this really wrong?

```
const ComponentNavLinkItem = useCallback(
    ({ to, icon, title }: { to: string; icon: string; title: string }) => (
        <NavLinkItem to={to} exact>
            <Icon icon={icon} />
            <Title>{title}</Title>
        </NavLinkItem>
    ),
    []
);
```

Comment: Same here - did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to do, but using directly the arguments should resolve the warning :

```
const ComponentNavLinkItem = useCallback(
    ({ to: string; icon: string; title: string }) => (
        <NavLinkItem to={to} exact>
            <Icon icon={icon} />
            <Title>{title}</Title>
        </NavLinkItem>
    ),
    [to, icon, title]
);
```

Don't forget to use them as dependencies at the bottom